# Testing JavaScript using RSpec/Capybara: How to improve my spec (for testing a textarea fullscreen feature)?

Tags: javascript, rspec, capybara

I have written a small JavaScript which can be applied to textareas and which makes it possible to maximise them using `Esc` key (or clicking on a label on the upper right of the textarea).

I'm no big JavaScript guru, and if anyone's interested, here's the code (CoffeeScript):

It basically wraps the `textarea` with a `div class="background"` during initialisation, and when one clicks on it (or presses `Esc`) a class `fullscreen` is toggled on it. The rest is CSS.

The whole stuff works pretty well, and I want to test it. I know there are a lot of JS test frameworks, but I'm used to RSpec and Capybara, and while these two don't offer everything a full-fledged JS testing framework provides, I think it should be enough to build some basic specs.

At the time being, my spec looks like this:

```
describe 'textarea fullscreen feature' do
  it 'allows to toggle fullscreen mode of "about" textarea', js: true do
    visit new_user_path

    within '.user_about' do # This is the input field (model "User", field "about")
      expect(page).to have_css '.textarea-fullscreenizer'
      expect(page).to have_css '.textarea-fullscreenizer-toggler', text: 'Toggle fullscreen (Esc)'

      expect {
        find('.textarea-fullscreenizer-toggler').click
      }.to change {
        page.has_css? '.textarea-fullscreenizer.textarea-fullscreenizer-focus'
      }.to true
    end
  end
end
```

This way I already make sure that the basic init process succeeds, and that clicking on the label adds the CSS class `fullscreen`. But it doesn't the following yet:

- Toggling using `Esc`
- Closing fullscreen on blur
- Changing opacity of the toggle label when hovering over it or when the textarea is focused
- The visual representation of the normal vs. fullscreen mode (e.g. that the width/height of the textarea changes)

What of these features can be implemented using RSpec/Capybara (with a sensible amount of code)?

PS: I know that this single spec could (should?) be divided into many single specs (each testing one functionality), but as JavaScript specs are very slow, I stick to the pragmatic approach of testing everything in one spec.